# Viewing IIS Web Configuration via PowerShell: HTTP Verbs

Tags: iis, powershell, httpverbs

I’m configuring IIS on some servers to add deny HTTP Verbs to the Request Filtering section. This was done using the following:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -Value @{VERB="OPTIONS";allowed="False"} -Name Verbs -AtIndex 0
```

…however, I want to be able to confirm the presence of this after it’s been configured. The following shows some properties but not the actual HTTP Verbs list:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -Name Verbs
```

I've since found the following command which does show a header for "Verbs" but it's empty regardless of "OPTIONS" being present in the IIS admin console:

```
Get-WebConfiguration system.webServer/security/RequestFiltering/verbs -Recurse | Select-Object Verbs
```

What do I need to add to list the verbs present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Get-WebConfiguration -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs/add' | ft verb,allowed
```

using the full Xpath to the XML node.

Sometimes it helps to look at the `applicationhost.config` file to figure out where exactly data is stored. You may use a Diff tool to see the differences after changing something in the UI.

To remove a specific verb, use:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs" -name "." -AtElement @{verb='OPTIONS'}
```

Comment: Bang on again thanks Peter ;)....and thanks for the advice.

Comment: Further to this, how would I remove the verb if I wanted to back this out?

Comment: Thanks for the update Peter. I actually remember seeing the command Clear-WebConfigurationProperty in another thread but that removes all values in one go from my understanding so Remove-WCP is more suitable for this scenario.